# jQuery click only works when double clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create many 'show more/less' on my website and the section I am stuck is my resume. It contains a table and I'd like to hide some of the rows on page load. I have manage to do it but the show more link only works on double click not single and I just can't figure out why and how I could fix it!

Below is my code for jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //About Section:
    jQuery("#about-showMore").click(function(){
        var about= document.getElementById("about-more");
        var showAbout= document.getElementById("about-showMore");

        if(about.style.display == 'none'){
            $("#about-more").show();
            showAbout.innerHTML = "(Show Less)";
        }
        else{
            $("#about-more").hide();
            showAbout.innerHTML = "(Show More)";
        }
    });


    //Resume Section:
    jQuery("#resume-showMore").click(function(){
        var resumeTitle= document.getElementsByClassName("table_title");
        var showResume= document.getElementById("resume-showMore");

        if(resumeTitle[0].style.display == 'none'){

            jQuery(".table_title").show();
            jQuery(".table_Des").show();    
        }
        else{
                jQuery(".table_title").hide();
                jQuery(".table_Des").hide();
                showResume.innerHTML = "(Show More)";
        }
    });
});
```

In my HTML I have added same name classes 'table_title' and 'table_Des' for those rows that I'd like to hide.

In CSS I have put 'display: none;' for these two classes:

```
tr.table_title{
    color: gray;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 50%;
    display: none;
}

tr.table_Des{
    color:gray;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `event.stopPropogation`, `preventDefault` and `bubbling`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead. You can use the same code for your resume section just change the ids and/or class names.

```js
$("#about-showMore").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#about-more').toggle();
    
    if($('#about-more').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).html('Show Less');
    } else {
        $(this).html('Show More');
    }
});
```

```css
#about-more {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="about-showMore">Show More</a>
<div id="about-more">More Stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You checked hidden status with css and showing it with jquery hide function. The best way I think is to use the only jquery hide/show or css display: block/none etc.

An example is as follows:

```
//Resume Section:
jQuery("#resume-showMore").click(function(){
    var resumeTitle= document.getElementsByClassName("table_title");
    var showResume= document.getElementById("resume-showMore");
    if(resumeTitle[0].style.display == 'none'){
        jQuery(".table_title").css('display','block');
        jQuery(".table_Des").css('display','block');  
    }
    else{
            jQuery(".table_title").css('display','none');
            jQuery(".table_Des").css('display','none');
            $("#resume-showMore").html("Show More");
    }
});
```